# How can i Post the data in QtCreator?

Tags: php, qt, post, qt-creator, qnetworkaccessmanager

Here is my code of Qt creator to send the data to PHP server and get the response.

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkAccessManager::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this ,          SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
QNetworkRequest *request = new   QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://68.169.55.41/fss/verifylogindetails.php"));
QByteArray postData =" {\"estate_id\":\"hsr\",\"emp_pin\":1234,\"emp_id\":\"santhosh\"}";
request->setRawHeader( "User-Agent" , "Mozilla Firefox" );
request->setRawHeader( "charset", "utf-8" );
request->setRawHeader( "Connection", "keep-alive" );
manager->post(*request, postData );
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
 QString data = reply->readAll().trimmed();
 qDebug() << data;
}
```

And here is my php code to receive the login data and comparing with database values and sending the response.

```
<?php
include 'config.php'; 
$data = json_decode($_SERVER['HTTP_JSON']);
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $password);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login_data_table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if((strcasecmp( $row['Emp_Id'], $data->emp_id) == 0) && ($row['Emp_Pin'] == $data- >emp_pin) && (strcasecmp( $row['Estate_Id'], $data->estate_id) == 0))
{
echo "SUCCESS"; 
}
else
{
echo "FAIL";
}
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My problem is..... Always i am getting FAIL message from server. Even i am sending correct login details. please help me where i am wrong in my code.

Comment: Your PHP code is very inefficient. I would change while loop with "WHERE" SQL condition. Another advice: use PDO, not mysql_* functions.

Comment: thanks for you reply. I have only one record in my DB. so, i used while loop instead of WHERE

Comment: Well, then you can just skip the while part and just call mysql_fetch_array once :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post a piece of code from my own program. Hopefully this will help:

```
void MainWindow::sendPost(url)
{
    QUrl params;
    params.addQueryItem("usrname", login);
    params.addQueryItem("passwrd", password);

    QByteArray data;
    data.append(params.toString());
    data.remove(0,1);

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(QNetworkRequest(url), data);
    CONNECT(reply, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
 QString data = reply->readAll().trimmed();
 qDebug() << data;
}
```

PHP code will get values from program using $_POST array ($_POST['usrname'] and $_POST['password'] hold both values sent from the program), not $_SERVER. I have no idea why did you use $_SERVER.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution solved my problem. Mr.Witold Sosnowski